# Convert JS Array into JSON Array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, javascript-objects

I have a js object with an array property created as follows:

```
response.options = [];
response.options.push({
     name: 'color',
     nodes: this.colourNodes
  }, {
     name: 'size',
     nodes: this.sizeNodes
});
```

I'm passing this to a rails endpoint through an ajax call, and saving it to my DB. The problem is that I need the JSON to be an array but currently it looks like this:

```
"options": {
        "0": {
            "name": "color",
            "nodes": ["node1","node2","node3"]
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "size",
            "nodes": ["node1","node2","node3"]
        }
    }
```

I realize js arrays are are actually just objects which is why the above happens, however I can't seem to figure out a clean way to manipulate either the js or rails code to get this instead:

```
"options": [
            {
                "name": "color",
                "nodes": ["node1","node2","node3"]
            },
            {
                "name": "size",
                "nodes": ["node1","node2","node3"]
            }
        ]
```

I think the easiest solution is probably just to construct an array out of the `options` object in rails but I can't seem to remove the root `0` and `1`  properties.

I'm sure I'm missing something here, any help is appreciated

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: I had tried doing a JSON.stringify of the whole `response` object which was giving me all sorts of problems on the rails side, but it seems like stringifying just the `options` property and parsing it on the other side did the trick. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike C for his comment, here's what I ended up doing:

`response.options = JSON.stringify(response.options);`

And then just `JSON.parse(params[:options])` on the rails side.

This seems crazy simple now that I have the answer but I was totally getting tunnel vision trying to stringify the whole object rather than just that property.